My sound stays at max volume or mute after Ubuntu 24.04 install. I am looking for new sound configuration fix using pipewire
Sound volume stays at max volume no matter what the increment shows as I toggle the volume buttons. Fresh Ubuntu 24.04 install. I had similar problem with earlier versions of Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04. Difference now is that pulseaudio is not default program 'pipewire' is now in place.
Before in previous versions, problem was fixed by editing the file below -
code /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common

adding these lines before PCM Block
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
After the 24.04 install there are no pulseaudio files to edit, so I am looking for a solution utilizing pipewire I suppose or if there is a walkback to pulseaudio and apply old fix.

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Lenovo Slim Pro 7 14ARP8
This worked for me, after I edited the config file below, I rebooted and voila. Volume works as expected now.
Set configuration line:
["api.alsa.soft-mixer"] = true
-in-
/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua


